# Chainings multi-to-one relations in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models: User, Query, Offer. The relation is that user has many queries and query has many offers.

In controller I use `$queries=User->query()->get();` (`query()` is a hasMany method in User model) and pass it to view as parameter. In view I want to display a table of queries from single user and count all offer made to each query.

Actually what I want to get, is a nested object $queries like

```
user:
  query1:
    offer1
    offer2
  query2:
    offer3
    offer4
```

How it should be coupled in models and how to use it in controller and view?

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like:

```
Class User extends Model{

protected $table = 'users';

public function query(){

  return $this->hasMany('App\Query');

}

}

Class Query extends Model{

protected $table = 'queries';

public function offer(){

  return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');

}

public function user(){

return $this->belongsto('App\User');

}

}

Class Offer extends Model{

protected $table = 'offers';

public function query(){

  return $this->belongsTo('App\Query');

}

}
```

Then in your controller you can have something like this:

```
public function showUser($id){

$user = User::with('query.offer')->find($id);
return View::make('user')->with('user', $user);

}
```

Then in your view you could have something like:

```
@foreach($user->query as $query)
   {{$query->title}}
      @foreach($query->offer as $offer)
         {{$offer->title}}
         {{$offer->amount}}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```